# Does PostgreSQL short-circuit its BOOL_OR() evaluation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, exists, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

#### `EXISTS` is faster than `COUNT(*)` because it can be short-circuited

A lot of times, I like to check for existence of things in SQL. For instance, I do:

```
-- PostgreSQL syntax, SQL standard syntax:
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT .. FROM some_table WHERE some_boolean_expression)

-- Oracle syntax
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT .. FROM some_table WHERE some_boolean_expression) THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END
FROM dual
```

In most databases, `EXISTS` is "short-circuited", i.e. the database can stop looking for rows in the table as soon as it has found one row. [This is usually much faster than comparing `COUNT(*) >= 1` as can be seen in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/09/14/avoid-using-count-in-sql-when-you-could-use-exists).

#### Using `EXISTS` with `GROUP BY`

Sometimes, I'd like to do this for each group in a `GROUP BY` query, i.e. I'd like to "aggregate" the existence value. There's no `EXISTS` aggregate function, but PostgreSQL luckily supports the [`BOOL_OR()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) aggregate function, like in this statement:

```
SELECT something, bool_or (some_boolean_expression)
FROM some_table
GROUP BY something
```

[The documentation mentions something about `COUNT(*)` being slow](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) because of the obvious sequential scan needed to calculate the count. But unfortunately, it doesn't say anything about `BOOL_OR()` being short-circuited. Is it the case? Does `BOOL_OR()` stop aggregating new values as soon as it encounters the first `TRUE` value?

Comment: What does the execution plan say? But I would expect the existence of the `group by` to require reading everything from the table, otherwise the data couldn't be correctly grouped

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: For example `"Aggregate  (cost=1.06..1.07 rows=1 width=4)"`. I.e. not very much. It's the same operation as when I put a `COUNT()` aggregate function. Or any number of aggregate functions. I wouldn't have expected the plan to display these details, though.

Comment: @LukasEder : Did you ever find an answer to the title question?

Comment: @MarkKCowan: No. I would've provided the answer here, if I had...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check for existence, I'm generally using a `LIMIT`/`FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` query:

```
SELECT .. FROM some_table WHERE some_boolean_expression
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

This generally stops execution after the first hit.

The same technique can be applied using `LATERAL` for each row (group) from another table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT something
          FROM some_table
         GROUP BY something
       ) t1
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ...
                        FROM ...
                       WHERE ...
                       FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY) t2
    ON (true)
```

In `t2` you can use a `WHERE` clause that matches any row for the group. It's executed only once per group and aborted as soon as the first hit was found. However, whether this performs better or worse depends on your search predicates and indexing, of course.

Comment: Are you sure that `LATERAL` join doesn't introduce a lot more cost to an in-memory aggregation per group? Would be interesting to measure formally. Btw, `LEFT JOIN LATERAL .. ON true` is the same as `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` :)

Comment: @LukasEder I mentioned that the actual mileage depends on details not mentioned in your question. CROSS vs. LEFT: not if the lateral derived table returns an empty set.

Comment: OK, I'll benchmark this on my side. Will be interesting! You're right about CROSS vs. LEFT, good point. So, in this particular case, LEFT changes the semantics of my query making the lateral join pointless for this use-case...

Comment: @LukasEder I don't get what's wrong with LEFT here. I guess you'd like to the the rows of t1 regardless whether the lateral query finds anything or not. Otherwise, CROSS join would be better, of course.

Comment: Never mind. In this particular case, LEFT and CROSS might do the same thing as we're both ultimately grouping by something, and you'd probably join again "using something", such that LEFT has no effect.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the exercise is that the lateral where clause might NOT hit any rows—otherwise, EXISTS seems to be a strange thing in the first place. However...\off :)